# UbuntuStudio 12.04 does not boot after install - no "intrd" image

Tags: 12.04, grub2, boot-failure

After installing Ubuntu Studio 12.04 from DVD onto the fourth hard disk, it fails to boot, even when explicitly choosing the fourth hard disk as the boot device.

I have SUSE 11.2 on the first 2 SCSI disks (which form a RAID) and Studio64 on the 1st IDE disk (that is, the third disk).

Looking at the `/boot` directory on the Ubuntu partition, I see there is no `initrd` image.

Editing the GRUB configuration file to include `(hd3,1)/vmlinuz` and of course `(hd3,1)/initrd` should fix the problem. But still GRUB gives a `file not found` error.

This appears to me that, no `mkintrd` during the booting process *(checked with LiveCD)*  runs like in OpenSUSE.

How do I create the `initrd` to make Ubuntu bootable.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot LiveCD
- Mount installed system
- Copy  `cdrom/casper/initrd.lz`  to `/boot` directory of the installed system
- Delete broken `initrd.img` link and create new link at `boot/inird.lz`
  the command is:

  `sudo ln -s /boot/initrd.lz initrd.img`
- Reboot
- Edit grub line to boot system by changing root to `sdd2` instead of `hdd2`

The System will boot now, but drop you into `initramfs` prompts

- Create directory `/mnt`  by command `mkdir mnt`
- Mount installed system, `mount /dev/sdd2 -t  ext4  /mnt`
- Change root to the installed system by this command `chroot /mnt`
- Now run this commands to go to `/boot` directory `cd boot`.
- Create new `initrd` by this command `update-initramfs -c -k all`
- Relink to new initrd by running this commands,

  - `cd ..`
  - `mv initrd.img initrd.old` and
  - `ln -s boot/initrd... initrd.img` , replace `...` with your `initrd` version number
- Exit chroot by command `exit`

Reboot now.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Ubuntustudio 12.04, similar happened, got the time to reboot message, hit enter, the DVD tray opened and shut before the install DVD could be removed, black screen, seemingly dead. Hit the reset button on the box, grub menu comes up without the new install, selected Ubuntu 10.10 which is on another partition, opened Konsole, update-grub, reboot, new install is now in the grub list, select it for boot; it boots, all is well.

Comment: After opening console type command sudo update-grub